# Specific function runs at the same moment on all of the views. How can I make it run one after the other?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am building Simon Says app using SwiftUI, and as I was building it I encountered a bug. 
The problem is with one specific function that I typed below. 
This function sets alphas of the Simon Says buttons (just a simple animation of pressing button) and sets them back to 0.5. I want this to run one at the time on each of the Views because so far the animation runs on all of the buttons at the same time.

All help will be appreciated!

```swift
for index in settings.guessArray {
            wait(time: 2.0) {
                settings.alphas[index] = 1.0
                wait(time: 0.3) {
                    settings.alphas[index] = 0.5
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work...

The waits execute asynchronously, so increase the initial wait time for each button to space them out in time:

```
var offset = 0.0
for index in settings.guessArray {
    wait(time: 2.0 + offset) {
        settings.alphas[index] = 1.0
        wait(time: 0.3) {
            settings.alphas[index] = 0.5
        }
    }

    // increase this value to increase the spacing between the buttons
    // lighting up
    offset += 0.3
}

//if you're using this function on multiple SwiftUI views at the same time
//consider placing the offset variable in @EnvironmentObject.
```

Comment: Thanks! That definitely worked. Although I had to assign this value to @EnvirnomentObject so that it can be read globally and be incremented globally because it runs on all of the views at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm flying blind here but what you achieve that with a semaphore. Adapt from the code below:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

for index in settings.guessArray {
    semaphore.wait() // When animation on one button begins
    wait(time: 2.0) {
        settings.alphas[index] = 1.0
        wait(time: 0.3) {
            settings.alphas[index] = 0.5
            semaphore.signal() // When animation on a button finishes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly that's not it. The buttons still light up at the same time. But I had to use DispatchSemaphore(value: 1) because for some reason the value 0 blocked button's animation.